# JQuery $.get() failing - readyState 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to track the progress of an archive compression through requesting a txt file made, and updated by PHP via JQuery $.get().

The process works except for 1 or 2 requests that fail at random intervals and return the following:

- readyState: 0
- responseText:
- status: 0
- statusText: error

In Chrome and Opera, there is also this next to the failed requests: "net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH"

Here is the code in question:

```
function check_compression(archive_name, progress_file, unique_compression_id) {

  $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
  });

  var request = $.get($.trim(progress_file));

  request.success(function(data) {

    var percent = parseInt(data);

    if(percent != 100) {

      setTimeout(function() {
        check_compression(archive_name, progress_file, unique_compression_id);
      }, 100);

    } else {
      // Not finished
    }

  });

  request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Just some error reporting
    setTimeout(function() {
      check_compression(archive_name, progress_file, unique_compression_id);
    }, 500);
  });

}
```

I have done a bit of research and ruled out possible situations:

Same Origin Policy issue: All requests are done to a file on the same server.  The progress_file var will be in a format such as: tmp_file.txt

AdBlock is not enabled.

Comment: "All requests are done to a local file" please clarify what you mean by local. Local to the file on a webserver, local to a file on your filesystem, etc.

Comment: that happens when the file is changed while reading it. if the length header is set before the file is read, then the file is changed, then read and sent, the Content-Length won't match your response length and the error you note will appear. if i had to guess, it happens just after 9% and 99%...

Comment: or if the file is blank or errors, the length can be off.

Comment: @KevinB Revised.  The file is requested in the same directory on the same server.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you, I did not know that.  The percentages vary based on how many files.  In a test of 800 some files, it failed around either 40%, or 90%  I will work on possible solutions for this and post back if I cannot find a solution